# Issues with onClick sequence

Tags: java, android, android-activity, calendarview

I am using Android Studio and run into a bit of an issue, here due to my inexperience. I have an `Activity` with a `CalendarView` and a `Button`. Upon pressing the `Button`, the Date selected in the `CalendarView` will be set into an `EditText` on the next `Activity`.

This works, but in a weird way. Usually, I will select a Date from the `CalendarView` and then when I click the `Button` the `Intent` will start but now it is the total opposite; I have to click on the `Button` and then choose a Date in order for the Intent to be started and to be redirected to another page.

**Here is my code:**

```
btnDone1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone1);
    btnDone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            calendar1.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
                    String date1 = dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
                    Intent doneD = new Intent(RentStartActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                    doneD.putExtra("Date1", date1);
                    startActivity(doneD);
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Please kindly show me in what way should I code it.
Help is appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `OnDateChangedListener` inside the button's `OnClickListener`, so it will only listen after you click the button. From what I understand, you want to do something like this:

```
btnDone1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone1);
calendar1.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
        btnDone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                String date1 = dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
                Intent doneD = new Intent(RentStartActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                doneD.putExtra("Date1", date1);
                startActivity(doneD);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This code sends the selected date to `SearchActivity` after you click the button.

Answer (score 1):

try following

```
String date1;
        calendar1.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
                date1 = dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;

            }
        });

        btnDone1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDone1);
        btnDone1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

                Intent doneD = new Intent(RentStartActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                doneD.putExtra("Date1", date1);
                startActivity(doneD);
            }
        });
```

In `SearchActivity` to get date.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String date = intent.getStringExtra("Date1");
```